# PreferenceFragment вывод введённого значения

Tags: android, android-shared-preferences, android-preferences

Есть вот такое Активити:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceFragment;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class MyPreferenceActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_preference);

    getFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.prefs_content, new SettingsFragment())
            .commit();
}

public static class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragment {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.settings);

    }
  }
}
```

И есть вот такой settings.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<EditTextPreference
    android:id="@+id/my_login"
    android:key="my_login"
    android:title="@string/settings_my_login"
    android:summary="Впишите Логин"
    android:dialogTitle="Впишите ваш Логин"
    />
</PreferenceScreen>
```

Всё работает, но есть вопрос. При тапе на EditText можно ввести какое-то своё значение, но после нажатия кнопка "Ок", диалог закрывается и не видно, какое значение ты ввёл. Как сделать вывод того, что ты ввёл, но не где-то в другом Активити или фрагменте, а прямо тут же. Например, чтобы вместо android:dialogTitle="Впишите ваш Логин" было выведено значение, которое ввёл юзер.

Спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

Через `registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener()` ловить событие изменения значений и печатать его где душе будет угодно.

Answer (score 0):

Все  настройки из `PreferenceFragment` сохраняются в `SharedPreferences`. После чего вы можете получить их значение в любом месте по ключу. Например в вашей активити:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);  
String login = sharedPref.getString("my_login", "");
```